# How to write the data to the plist

Tags: iphone, string, ipad, plist

HI 
can u send me  sample code to add the data to the .plist. .my plist was in this format as follows.kindly help me out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<string>http://localhost:8888/sample</string>
<string>http://localhost:8888/sample</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

i wil send the url string from the implementation code.kindly help me in this pls..

```
-(IBAction)AddFieldid)sender;
{
NSMutableArray *myPrimaryinfo = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6]retain];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string",nil];

[myPrimaryinfo addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"],nil]forKeys:keys]];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDire ctory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"urls.plist"];
[myPrimaryinfo writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
NSLog(@"PrimaryInfo array: %@", myPrimaryinfo);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should try to accept the answers on your previous questions in order to encourage people to keep answering your future questions.

Comment: Hi Claus
i think u have seen my code.can u guide me wher im making the mistake.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this would work (not very good at iphone stuff):

```
// Loading
NSString *path = ...
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Manipulating
NSObject *newElement = ...
[array addObject:newElement];

// Storing
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

By pressing "ALT" + double clicking on a class name opens up the docu for this class along with a list of methods and so on. Take a look there, too!

Comment: I have tried this Zeiss,but its not writing any content to the plist can u get me any sample code for that so that i can check where im making mistake

Comment: use the debugger or the output to check that you have actually loaded the right file. The best example code I have is above.

Comment: i have tried the same code Zeiss.but the problem is in Plist its not getting saved,tats y? i asked the sample code for that to chk the Plist and its structure

Comment: I don't understand a word. If you use the virtual pod, you should be able to see the saved .plist file under `Library/App.. Support/iPhone Simulator` somewhere. Otherwise, you could use a NSLabel to show the content of your array.

Comment: ya but some of the post they are saying tat we cant save the plist in to the device .can u recheck and tel me Zeiss please

Comment: Afaik, your app can only write into your sandbox. Make sure the path points at a file in your sandbox.