# How to retrieve text message

Tags: iphone, nsstring, plist

This is code how I save text

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.plist"];
    NSString *savedString = _textView.text;
    //NSString *saveString=_textView2.text;
    [savedString writeToFile:documentTXTPath atomically:YES ];
```

Please tell me how to retrieve it. Please help me. And how to make plist in my project itself.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick way would be:

```
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error: NULL];
```

Don't forget to do your error handling.

Be aware that this will block the main thread until the whole text file has been loaded. If you're dealing with large files, you may want to use [`mmap` and `munmap`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/Articles/MappingFiles.html).

As a side note, if you'll ever want to load a text file over a network, *never* use `NSString stringWithContentsOfURL` (or any of the *WithContentsOfURL methods in general). This method will block the main thread until the file has been downloaded. In that case, use `NSURLConnection` or `ASIHTTPRequest` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `NSString` class method [`stringWithContentsOfFile:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think , you might want to know, how to deal with plist in application ...

Here is the SO post to get data from plist and to write to plist ...

[How to read a plist data and get int from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037612/how-to-read-a-plist-data-and-get-int-from-it)

[How to write the data to the plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227094/how-to-write-the-data-to-the-plist)

Here is the Code to read the data in dictionary from plist...

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *myplistPath = [path stringbyAppendingPathComponent:@"myplist.plist"];

NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myplist];
```